# Андроид-Студио: как установить по умолчанию для новых файлов-разметок разметку LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-studio

Вопрос вынесен в тему. Но тут требуется повторить.
Как установить в Андроид-Студио по умолчанию для новых файлов-разметок разметку LinearLayout вместо стандартной.

Answer (score 1):

В `Android Studio` - `Preferences` - `Editor` - `File and Code Templates` - Вкладка `Other`, там стандартные шаблоны.

Comment: К сожалению, не разобрался. Для начала, давайте для других читателей укажем актуальный путь на сегодня: File - Other Settings - Default Settings - Editor - File and Code Templates - Вкладка Other. Правильно? Теперь, там есть 2 шаблона разметки, один из них Линейный вертикальный. Но что нужно сделать, чтобы именно он был по умолчанию? Удалить стоящий выше него иной шаблон?

Comment: Для начала - путь я указал правильный. Вы же пошли другим путем, разница между нашими путями = вы видите только дефолтные настройки, по моему пути = все настройки. Оба варианта правильны. Экспериментируйте, Вообще когда вы создаете файл разметки правой кнопкой мыши на папке Layout - New - Layout Resource File , все что вам нужно это указать имя и во втором поле разметку.

Comment: Но я не могу найти Preferences. Нет такого пункта в меню первого уровня, где есть File, Edit и т.д. И уж с самого начала, я не вижу и Android Studio :), кроме как на заголовке виндусового окна. Куда же смотреть? Я прицепился к этой разметке по умолчанию, так как создаю разметку одновременно с классом Окна (Активити), - эту операцию любезно предоставляет студио, одновременно прописывая в манифесте класс.

Comment: В вашем случае - иконка гайка с ключом на панели инструментов. как под виндой через контекстное меню зайти я не помню =)

Comment: Именно в этом случае я уже вам не помогу, так как я не пользуюсь автоматическим созданиям файлов.

Comment: Нашел, благодарю! Правда она называется Сеттинг. Подскажите, а под какой ОС Вы используете Студио и чем это вызвано? А также почему Вы не используете автоматическое создание файлов, ведь все то же самое, нет дополнительных возможностей, при этом приходится все писать/выбирать руками?

Comment: я сижу под Mac OS X, почему перешел - не помню. Наверно потому, что их ноутбуки для моих целей лучше подходят. Автоматическое создание файлов - не привык. Раньше такой Фишки не было, я начинал с эклипса, потом чистая IDEA, потом уже Android Studio. Я конечно пользуюсь горячими клавишами, но создание файлов - это минимальное действие. Наверное по этому и не привык )

Comment: Что я там не менял, к сожалению, не помогло. Все равно, признателен за помощь.